# How to resolve the following fatal error with Apache spark in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: xml, hadoop, xslt

The error message i got upon running hadoop namenode -format:

```
[Fatal Error] core-site.xml:8:5: The element type "property" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</property>".
15/11/12 14:53:07 FATAL conf.Configuration: error parsing conf file: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/administrator/Downloads/FlareGet/Compressed/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 5; The element type "property" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</property>".
15/11/12 14:53:07 ERROR namenode.NameNode: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/administrator/Downloads/FlareGet/Compressed/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 5; The element type "property" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</property>".
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:1237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:1037)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.setStartupOption(NameNode.java:1250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1288)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/administrator/Downloads/FlareGet/Compressed/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 5; The element type "property" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</property>".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:338)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:1142)
    ... 6 more

15/11/12 14:53:07 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at Lenovo-G580/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

My code in core-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                </name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
                <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
                <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>fs.default.name</name>
                <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
                <description>The name of the default file system. A URI whose scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation. The uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming the FileSystem implementation class. The uri's authority is used to determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

All the tags have been properly ended.However the error is still displaying and I am not able to figure it out.Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML has a problem at the first property: the tag name is closed two times and never opened. It should be:

```
    <property>
            <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
            <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
            <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
    </property>
```

Comment: Check the new edited code.This is the present file code and still is giving the same error.

Comment: There is yet the same error in the code in your post. You have two `</name>` in the second line of what I posted: the first one has to be a `<name>`.